# How do we draw some auxiliary lines for typical values of the function in a 2D Plot?

Tags: plotting, grid-lines

I want to draw some auxiliary lines for typical values of the function in my graph like these blue dashed lines:
[image: auxiliary lines]

Also, I want to put the values of the lines by the lines like above one.

Do you know any smart and easy way to achieve these rather than using `GridLine` options many times manually?

The following is what I did and got, and not cool:

```
f[x_] := x/E^x;
Plot[f[x], {x, -2.5, 10}, GridLines -> {{{1, {Blue, Dashed}}}, {{f[1], {Blue, Dashed}}}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Use `Epilog` along with `Point[]`, `Line[]`, and maybe `Dashed`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A tiny bit of modification on JasonB's answer

```
Plot[f[x], {x, -2.5, 10}, Ticks -> {{1}, {1/E}}, 
 GridLines -> Automatic, PlotStyle -> Black, AxesLabel -> {x, y},  
 Epilog -> {AbsolutePointSize[5], Point /@ {{1, 0}, {0, f[1]}}, Blue, 
   Point[{1, f[1]}], Dashed, 
   Line[{{{1, 0}, {1, f[1]}}, {{0, f[1]}, {1, f[1]}}}]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can supply any `Graphics` primitives directly to the `Plot` using [`Epilog`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Epilog.html)

```
Plot[f[x], {x, -2.5, 10}, 
 Epilog -> {Blue, Thick, Dashed, 
   Line[{{{1, 0}, {1, f[1]}}, {{0, f[1]}, {1, f[1]}}}]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

For your plot you can also put those point labels in using the [`Text`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Text.html) graphics primitive, like `Epilog -> {Text[Style["1/e", 13], {-.4, f[1]}], Blue, Thick, Dashed, Line[...]}`

Comment: I don't get it... You are a postdoc again? :)

Comment: @BlacKow, he just wanted his old name back, tho Kuba had previously proposed "JasonB is me", but belatedly.

Comment: @BlacKow - I couldn't handle the real world so I went back to academia....  And if I go for a silly name again it will be "American Pie's Jason Biggs"

Answer (score 5):

For the fun of reproducing the original picture somewhat faithfully (yes, I can't seem to focus on real work this morning...):

```
f[x_] := x/E^x;
Plot[
 f[x], {x, -2.5, 10},
 Ticks -> {
   {0, 1},
   {{1/E, Row[{Style["1/", FontFamily -> "Times"], Style["e", FontFamily -> "Times", Italic]}]}}
 },
 TicksStyle -> Directive[Black, 12],
 PlotRange -> {{-1.2, 5.2}, {-0.9, 0.9}}, PlotRangePadding -> None,
 PlotStyle -> Black,
 GridLines -> {Range[-1, 5], Range[-1, 1, 0.5]},
 Epilog -> {
   Inset[Style["y = xe^(-x)", Bold, Italic, FontFamily -> "Times", 12], {3.7, 0.57}],
   PointSize[0.015], Point[{{0, 1/E}, {1, 0}}],
   {Blue, Point[{1, 1/E}]},
   Arrowheads[.035], Arrow[{{0, 0}, {0, 0.9}}], 
   Arrow[{{0, 0}, {5.2, 0}}],
   Inset[Style["0", 12], {0.14, -.073}],
   Inset[Style["x", Italic, FontFamily -> "Times", 14], {5.1, -0.073}],
   Inset[Style["y", Italic, FontFamily -> "Times", 14], {-0.2, 0.85}],
   Blue, Dashed, Line[{{0, 1/E}, {1, 1/E}}], Line[{{1, 0}, {1, f[1]}}],
 },
 AspectRatio -> 0.75
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: no points... hehe

Comment: @BlacKow Ha! Forgot those! Thank you, you saved me from going back to work :-)

Comment: Still no blue dot...

Comment: ...and the label too. ;)

Comment: @J.M. Added those as well, and spread some upvotes all around for the good fun! :-)

Comment: You are now a certified faker; congratulations! ;) (Unfortunately I cannot upvote again.)

Comment: @J.M. I feel accomplished now. I'd love to put that title on my résumé, but I'm afraid it may raise some eyebrows at my day job :-)